# Hadoop - MapReduce runs extremely slow when using YARN

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, hadoop-yarn

I know there is another question about this, but there are no answers yet, so I'm going to try and ask it in a more detail.

I am running a map-reduce job using Hadoop 2.2.0 on a 2 node cluster that I have setup on Amazon 2 EC2 instances; the master node is a medium instance and the slave node is also a medium instance. It runs extremely slowly, it takes over 17 minutes, but when I run the same exact job on the same cluster without yarn it runs in under 1 minute. Here is what my mapred-site.xml looks like:

```
    <configuration>
      <property> 
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name> 
        <value>yarn</value> 
      </property>
    </configuration>
```

If I change the mapreduce.framework property to 'local, so that the file simply reads:

```
    <configuration>
      <property> 
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name> 
        <value>local</value> 
      </property>
    </configuration>
```

I can then run the same map-reduce job in less than a minute. However, I would like to use YARN, so that I can track the map-reduce job through the webapp. When I run the job with the mapreduce.framework property set to yarn it takes 17+ minutes to run the same exact job. I cannot imagine that YARN would slow down a map-reduce job to such an extreme level.

I am also using "top" to track my CPU usage, and it seems that when I run it with yarn, the CPU usage is split between the different nodes, however, when I change run it with "local" all of the processing is done on the master node. I'm not sure how this makes sense, because it seems to me, that when the CPU processing is split between the different nodes, it should run faster, not slower. Is there something I forgot to configure in Hadoop to make running on a cluster faster?

Here are the rest of my configuration files:

core-site.xml

```
    <configuration>
      <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://namenode:8020</value>
      </property>
    </configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
    <configuration>
      <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>dfs.permissions</name>
        <value>false</value>
      </property>
      <property> 
        <name>fs.checkpoint.dir</name> 
        <value>file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop/hdfs/snn</value> 
      </property> 
      <property> 
        <name>fs.checkpoint.edits.dir</name> 
        <value>file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop/hdfs/snn</value> 
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop/hdfs/nn</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop/hdfs/nn</value>
      </property>
    </configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
    <configuration>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>namenode:8031</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>namenode:8032</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>namenode:8030</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
        <value>namenode:8033</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
        <value>namenode:8088</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
      </property>
      <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
      </property>
    </configuration>
```

Is there something wrong with the way I set this up? Has anyone else ran into this problem? Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wish i still remember where I read this so I can give you a reference. You won't benefit with yarn unless you have large size cluster.